# How to do reflection on underlying DB columns in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm

Its not uncommon, when you have an entity, to want to know the underlying database's column width and to use that to ensure validation and interface limits are set and handled.

If you annotate a column in your entity with something like @column(length=30) then you can interrogate the annotation. I am interested in knowing how to find the value when there is no column length annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use JDBC to [get the DatabaseMetaData from the Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData%28%29), and then asking for the columns you're interested into, using [getColumns()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).